# Issues with reading and writing on individual lines

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to have my batch file add to an amount in main.config, but it just keeps writing "Echo Is Off" in the file.

This is the batch file that gets called by seal. It reads the line, sets it as %line%, and adds to it. Then it prints that back to the same line.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%G IN (main.config) DO if not defined line set "line=%%G"
set /a ress==%line%+1
call :RL RL 2 main.config %ress%
goto :eof
:RL
(For /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%~3" ^| find /n /v ""') DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (if "%%B" EQU "" (Echo+>> "%~3.NEW") ELSE ((Echo %%B)>> "%~3.NEW")) ELSE ((Echo %~4)>> "%~3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RENAMER
(REN "%~1" "%~nx1.BAK") & (MOVE /Y "%~1.BAK" "%TEMP%\" >NUL) & (REN "%~1.NEW" "%~nx1") & (GOTO:EOF)
```

This is the start of seal.bat

```
@echo off
call exithandl.bat
:main
500 lines of absolute trash
```

Comment: There is an `=` sign too much in line `set /a ress==%line%+1`. Why do you concatenate so many commands and so make your code hard to read and debug?

Comment: To start with, try changing `set /a ress==%line%+1` to `Set/A ress=line+1`.

Comment: It fixed the initial problem, however my values will only go up to 2 for whatever reason. I have tried messing around with the values that determine line placement.

    for /f "skip=1" and
    (For /F "tokens=1*

but nothing seems to change.